# QGIS Script with gdalogr:convertformat

Tags: qgis, python, gdalogr

I want to save a KML point file with attributes and descriptions from a generic point vector layer, and I need to do this at the end of a processing chain inside QGIS graphical modeler. 
Ideally, I would have the option to choose the icons of the KML points.

From here, I've started to use the "Convert Format" algorithm from GDAL asuming that this would be the simplest option.

I've wrote the following script to do so (but I'm missing how to call the `-dsco NameField=RegionName` option to have the descriptions correctly labeled)

```
##Convert=name
##Layer=vector

layer = processing.getObject(Layer)
output_path = "C:/Users/jmgc/Desktop/testes_script/" + layer.name() 

processing.runalg("gdalogr:convertformat", Layer, 15, '', output_path)
```

Adding the `-dsco NameField=RegionName` gives me an error:

```
##Convert=name
##Layer=vector

layer = processing.getObject(Layer)
output_path = "C:/Users/jmgc/Desktop/testes_script/" + layer.name() 

processing.runalg("gdalogr:convertformat", Layer, 15, -dsco NameField=RegionName, output_path)
```

Any thoughts on how to solve this on my prescriptive or following another one would be helpful.

Comment: Try putting `-dsco NameField=RegionName` inside quotation marks. I.e. `'-dsco NameField=RegionName'` so that it is read as a string.

Comment: Joseph, indeed it worked. I could swear i've tried that earlier...

Comment: It would also be possible to edit the marker icon using this script?

Comment: Don't worry about it, happens to most of us :). What do you mean by "marker icon"?

Comment: The default marker icon when opening the points with Google Earth. I guess I wasn't very clear.
Also noticed when using the `-dsco` option the file looses the attribute table data when clicking over the icon. Without this option, all the attributes appears when clicking the icon (Google Earth)

Comment: Sorry, can't tell you. I'm not a user of Google Earth =)

Comment: UPDATE: The name of the fields on the attribute table must be different than the field used inside the `-dsco` option, in order to be saved to the kml and to appear in Google Earth.